# failed to run commands: fork/exec /usr/bin/pwsh: no such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

getting this error after creating system manager document,

```
---
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Command Document Example JSON Template"
parameters:
  Message:
    type: "String"
    description: "Example"
    default: "Hello World"
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runPowerShellScript"
  name: "example"
  inputs:
    runCommand:
    - 'sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y'
    - 'sudo apt install -y httpd'
    - 'sudo systemctl start httpd'
    - 'sudo systemctl enanle httpd'
    - 'echo "{{Message}} from $(hostname -f)" > /var/www/html/index.html'
```

Please let me know wht i have to do for this error ?

Need to install httpd in all 3 servers i have.

Comment: Do you have powershell installed on the instances?

Comment: No, should i install that and then the docker ? and can i do it thru ssm

Comment: still its didnt work like this. 

solution is you have to use runShellScript in place of runPowerShellScript

Comment: So this issue is solved?